# environ variable not visible to flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-venv, dotenv

Flask app was not getting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI value from .env in order to create tables in ProstgreSQL db.

Here's config:

```
import os

class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
...
```

I tried

```
>>> from app.extensions import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

and

```
>>> from app import create_app 
>>> app = create_app()
>>> from app.extensions import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

and

```
>>> from app import create_app
>>> app=create_app()
>>> app.app_context().push() 
>>> from app.extensions import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

With a little help from my friends on Stackoverflow, I got to the working proc:

```
>>> from dotenv import load_dotenv
>>> load_dotenv()
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
>>> from app import create_app
>>> app = create_app()
>>> app.app_context().push()   
>>> from app.extensions import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

Question: Where is the bug? `config.py` has `import os` line. `python_dotenv` is installed. What shall I do to avoid using the first four lines in the proc above?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until `load_dotenv()`, whatever is in `.env` is ignored. The question is where to do that `load_dotenv()`. It has to happen before anyone reached in to `os.environ` expecting something from `.env` to be there.

The usually place, if you're following the pattern from the Flask Mega Tutorial, is right before

```
class Config(object):
```

E.g., https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/blob/v0.15/config.py

Comment: Dave, I've modified `config` according to Grinberg's tutorial. Unfortunately, removing the first four lines in the proc and relying on the same in `config` gives me the old unsatisfactory result:

`>>> from app import create_app`

`>>> app = create_app()`

`>>> app.app_context().push()`

`>>> from app.extensions import db`

`>>> db.create_all()`

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`

...
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'`

`>>>`

Comment: Dave, thanks to you I got on the right track. I had to adjust for a more complex directory structure in the path call. Things are running now. Thanks again.